# Combining or skipping version of the core data model

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch, cocoa, core-data, core-data-migration

During development of a new feature, I have versioned my core data model a few times, always using lightweight migration. I am working on v1.5 of my app and now have versions 1.5.0, 1.5.1, 1.5.1, etc of my core data model. Only the final version is going to be used by a deployed product - to put it another way, had I been better able to predict the model I would end up with, my v1.5.0 would have looked like v1.5.99.

Is there some way to consolidate the intermediate versions, so that the migration is one-step?  If I don't do this, will the migration run multiple times, and will there be a performance impact?

I am considering restoring my v1.4 version and manually re-creating the final model version as the only new version, but am not looking forward to re-adding all of the other code that has been updated in the same branch.

Answer (score 0):

If (1) you don't have any data stored with the 1.5.0, 1.5.1, etc. versions, and (2) migration from 1.4 to 1.5.99 can happen automatically, then you can just remove the intervening versions from your data model.